# Cannot select S/MIME Certificate to sign email on iOS

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, security, keychain

I installed my certificate along side all certificates in the chain.
It shows as trusted in my settings.
However for my email-account I cannot enable signing because "No valid certificates found."

[image]
[image]

Things i have already checked:

- the issued name is the same as the email sender i am trying to sign with
- full chain is imported and certificate is valid & trusted